# How do you return an object that takes pure virtual (const ref) arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory, pure-virtual

I have an object that holds a list of abstract class instances.

```
class A { };  // abstract class

class B {
 public:
  void addA(const A& a) {
    list_of_a_.push_back(&a);
  }
 private:
  std::vector<const A*> list_of_a_;
};
```

A is abstract so I'm storing them in the vector as pointers and passing it along as const reference. I have different subclasses of A.

Then I have a factory-like function that creates B and returns it.

```
B CreateB() {
  B b;
  DerivationOfA a;  // subclass of abstract class A.
  b.addA(a);
  return b;
}

int main() {
  B b = CreateB();
  b.DoSomethingWithA();  // bad memory, 'a' was destroyed.
}
```

The problem is once B is returned from the "create" function, the instance of A is destroyed on the stack. Same thing happens when I use a smart pointer. I want to avoid using regular pointers to avoid extra memory management issues.

Is there a trick to doing this so that I can keep the `CreateB` function, avoid using pointers, but still be able to pass abstract classes into `B`? I'm okay with using pass by value, it's just that C++ doesn't allow doing that with abstract classes.

**Edit**: I know why it happens, but I'm not sure how to get around it when using pure virtual objects. Outside of using C pointers, which I want to avoid, I'm not sure how to avoid the scoping issue.

**Edit 2**: Pure virtual *classes* instead of *objects* to be more precise.

**Edit 3**: *Abstract* classes instead of *pure virtual* classes to satisfy the nitpicking.

Comment: This have nothing to do with virtual functions or abstract classes, but everything with you storing pointers to local variables. Think about using pointers all the way if you have abstract base classes, and then think about pointer ownership and how they can be managed with smart pointers.

Comment: there is no such think as a "pure virtual object". The term "pure virtual class" can be translated as "class that cannot be instantiated", ie you cannot create an object of that class

Comment: You need to `new` up `DerivationOfA` (or maybe `make_unique` or `make_shared` if you prefer, which internally are going to end up doing `new` among other things). There's no way around it, because you can't keep pointers to local variables and you can't do anything like vector<A> while supporting derived classes.

Comment: try move semantics?

Comment: Pure virtual functions. Abstract classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have confusing design. It is bad idea receive object by reference and save its pointer.

- Use smart pointer.
- If you want to keep object by pointer you need to allocate it on heap (by `new` operator) and release (by `delete` operator) at your container (class with vector member).
- If you want to pass it by reference you need to guarantee that object will not be deleted. Or you need to make copy of that object during that function call.

In some libraries containers receive poiner with just created object and save it in internal data and responsible for its deletion. If you do not use smart pointers you need to define and keep in mind which object is master of object referenced by pointer. It is no simple problem to manage objects by pointer. Smart poiners make that more simpler.

Comment: I ended up using a smart shared_ptr to store these objects. That way it can be copied and avoids stack.

Answer (score 0):

Define a move constructor for B.

```
B factory() {
  B x;
  // some code

  return std::move(x);
  // return x; if with copy elision
}
```

Should work.

If move semantics is not an option.

```
struct B {
 public:
  class Holder {
   public:
    static Holder NewHolder() {
      return Holder(new B{});
    }
    B *ptr_;

   private:
    Holder(B *ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
  };

  B() : resource_(new int) {
    std::cout << "Construct" << std::endl;
  }

  B(Holder x) {
    resource_ = x.ptr_->resource_;
    x.ptr_->resource_ = nullptr;
    delete x.ptr_;
  }

  ~B() {
    std::cout << resource_ << " deleted by " << this << std::endl;
    delete resource_;
  }

  int *resource_;
};

B::Holder factory() {
  B::Holder holder = B::Holder::NewHolder();
  B &b = *holder.ptr_;
  // some code

  return holder;
}

int main() {
  B b = factory();

  return 0;
}
```

Holder is a nested class which holds a B allocated by new. And this B will not be destroyed until the contructor `B(Holder x)` steal the resouce from holder, then the constructor delete the empty B.

Answer (score -1):

The `CreateB` function creates an object `b` on the stack and when we return from that function, stack is unwound and `b` goes out of scope.

You can create the object `b` in the `main` function and then call `addA` function on that object.

EDIT

Create `b` on heap and return reference to it.

```
B* CreateB() {
    B *b = new B;
    // rest of the code
    return b;
}
```

Comment: That's what I originally had, but it gets messy (the above is a very trivial example of the whole code). I would like to have a factory function that handles the mess and keeps main() clean.

Comment: You can allocate `b` on heap using a `new`. B *b = new B;

Comment: shouldn't `return *b` be `return b`? `b` is a pointer, so returning it is like returning the reference of something